# How can I access spring resource bundle key/value in a java code block (jsp file)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, resourcebundle

I'm trying to grab a key/value pair from some resource bundles I'm asked to work with

Normally within our block of HTML (in a JSP file) we might have something like

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<h1><spring:message code="gr.common.title"/></h1>
```

However, I want to do something with the String in Java before outputting it in HTML, something like

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%
// pseudo below
String foo = "This is my %s title".format(PSEUDO_MESSAGE("gr.common.title"));
%>
<h1><%= foo %></h1>
```

I found [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/after.html) example but this seems to be within a .java file or equivalent

Comment: @Nambari I've revised the second block of code for clarity, it's a mock up but I am trying to achieve something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `core` tag lib `set` tag

```
<c:set var="toDoSomeFormat">
    <spring:message code="gr.common.title" />
</c:set>
```

The `set` element takes its value from its content.

Then use your formatting with `${toDoSomeFormat}`